# MVC passing parameter is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to pass a parameter via url to a ASP.NET MVC controller. I am using custom routes for the first time and I am not sure if I am missing something.

Here is the url I am calling:

```
http://localhost:2053/agent-edit/?id=12
```

Here is my custom url:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "agent", url: "agent", defaults: new { controller = "Agents", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "agent-add", url: "agent-add", defaults: new { controller = "Agents", action = "Add" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "agent-edit", url: "agent-edit/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Agents", action = "Edit" });
```

and here is my my contoller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
        bla_Agent Agent = bla_Agent.getSingleAgent(id);
        return View(Agent);
}
```

I can navigate to all my other url fine it is just when I try to send an id where it does not seem to work. I just get a 404 not found error in Chrome Console. Before I added the `{id}`, I could also navigate to the url perfectly so view is working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have defined `agent-edit/{id}` as your URL template, you should be calling it like this: `http://localhost:2053/agent-edit/12`

Answer (score 0):

try the last route as:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "agent-edit", url: "agent-edit/{id}", defaults: new {
    controller = "Agents",
    action = "Edit",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your action like: `http://localhost:2053/agent-edit/?id=12`

then you have to change the last route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "agent-edit", url: "agent-edit", defaults: new { controller = "Agents", action = "Edit" });
```

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:2053/agent-edit/?id=12` is not working because it does not match the pattern you have specified in the routes. It should therefore be like `http://localhost:2053/agent-edit/12` since the controller is expecting an Id to be appended at the end of the route.
Furthermore, if you wish the id to be optional try using :

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as Marc_s said in comments . When you have your route as

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "agent-edit", url: "agent-edit/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Agents", 
action = "Edit" });
```

Then you dont need to call the url as with query parameters . you can simply do

```
http://localhost:2053/agent-edit/12
```

The reason is the 12 would be taken as route values and then it is passed onto corresponding action which you are callling into from from controller

In your case it is

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    bla_Agent Agent = bla_Agent.getSingleAgent(id);
    return View(Agent);
}
```

so you just need to call it like `http://localhost:2053/agent-edit/12`

Yes if you are passing another value `AgentName`  . Then you have to pass it via query string likely

`http://localhost:2053/agent-edit/12?AgentName=ABC`

And your controller would be

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id,string AgentName)
{
    bla_Agent Agent = bla_Agent.getSingleAgent(id);
    return View(Agent);
}
```

Now the reason how it works  is they way you map in route map in route config . The route in which you have declared in route config is expecting  `{id}` as route value so it can be passed by you as trailing slash . But in case of `AgentName`. Its not mentioned in Route value parameters . So it would be passed as query string with url with querystring key value pair. Unlike just route value as `Id`.

I hope it should be clear for you to understand